# Topology, equivalent statements, nets, boundary

Tags: general-topology, nets

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $V\subseteq X$. Then is equivalent:
>
> 1) $x\in\partial V$
>
> 2) For every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ is $V\cap U\neq\emptyset\neq (X\setminus V)\cap U$
>
> 3) It exists nets $(x_\lambda)_\lambda$ in $V$ and $(y_\lambda)_\lambda$ in $X\setminus V$ with $x_\lambda, y_\lambda\to x$

My thoughts:

Edit: Following the hint of Daniel Schepler:

$x\in\partial V\Leftrightarrow x\in\overline{V}\setminus V^\circ\Leftrightarrow x\in\overline{V}\wedge x\notin V^\circ\Leftrightarrow x\in\overline{V}\wedge x\notin V\setminus \overline{(X\setminus V)}\\\Leftrightarrow x\in\overline{V}\wedge x\in\overline{(X\setminus V)}$

Since $x\in\overline{V}$ I can use what was shown here: [Topological space, equivalent statements, net, closure, neighborhood](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2465829/topological-space-equivalent-statements-net-closure-neighborhood)

So we just have to show the "2nd half".

Now I want to show, that $(X\setminus V)\cap U\neq\emptyset$
Suppose $(X\setminus V)\cap U=\emptyset$, then is $U\subseteq (X\setminus V)^c=V$, also $U\subseteq V$. Then is $U_x\subseteq V^\circ$, hence $x\in V^\circ$. 
But it is $x\in\partial V=\overline{V}\setminus V^\circ$. Contradiction.

Can someone give a hint for $(1)\Leftrightarrow (3)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: show that $x \in \partial V$ if and only if $x \in \overline V$ and $x \in \overline{X \setminus V}$.  Then the equivalence $(1) \Leftrightarrow (2)$ reduces to the similar standard equivalence regarding when $x \in \overline V$, and similarly for the equivalence $(1) \Leftrightarrow (3)$.

Comment: Thank you. I could show that. I edit it into my question.

Comment: So, to answer the question you edited in: you know $x \in \overline{X \setminus V}$ if and only if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, we have $(X \setminus V) \cap U \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: Can I do one direction like this: Suppose $(X\setminus V)\cap U=\emptyset$, then $U\subseteq (X\setminus V)^c= V$. Therefore $x\in V$. Contradiction to $x\in\overline{X\setminus V}$

Comment: $\Rightarrow$: Let $(X\setminus V)\cap U\neq\emptyset$ for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$. Since $X$ is a neighborhood of $x$, we get $(X\setminus V)\cap X=X\setminus V\neq\emptyset$. Therefore $x\in X\setminus V\subseteq\overline{X\setminus V}$

Comment: Is this correct? Can you give a hint on (1)$\Leftrightarrow$ (3)

Comment: Umm... your proof that $\partial V = \overline V \cap \overline{X \setminus V}$, along with the facts on the page you linked, are already sufficient to finish the proof without needing to repeat any arguments or give new arguments.  And for $(1) \Leftrightarrow (3)$, the page also has the fact $x \in \overline V$ if and only if there is some net in $V$ with limit $x$.

Comment: (The only possible wrinkle in $(1) \Leftrightarrow (3)$ is if the statement of (3) technically requires both nets to be indexed by the same directed set - which isn't clear whether that's what it's requiring.  If it is required, then in the proof of $(1) \Rightarrow (3)$ you can take the individual nets, then take the product of the two directed sets.)

Comment: I do not think that is has to be indexed the same way. So with $\partial V=\overline{V}\cap\overline{X\setminus V}$ and that I showed the statement already for $x\in\overline{V}$ is already enough for $(1)\Leftrightarrow (2)$? (Both parts of it?)

Comment: You just apply the fact "$x \in \overline S \Leftrightarrow \forall U ~\mathrm{a~neighborhood~of~}x, S \cap U \ne \emptyset$" twice: once with $S = V$ and once with $S = X \setminus V$.

Comment: Yes, but for $S=V$ it is already proofen, so I just apply it for $S=X\setminus V$ and proceed as above?

Comment: It's already proven for *all* $S$.

Comment: But why, I do not see it.

Comment: Because the argument on the linked page works for any $V$, so it proves a statement $\forall X ~ \mathrm{a~topological~space}, \forall V \subseteq X, \forall x \in X, x \in \overline V \leftrightarrow (\cdots)$.  (And it doesn't matter whether you call the variable $V$ or $S$.)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I misunderstood you to be honest... And the implication $(1)\Leftrightarrow (3)$?

Comment: I already said that: use the fact from the linked page that $x \in \overline S$ if and only if there exists some net in $S$ with limit $x$.